Helicity as a good quantum number
Why helicity $h (p)$ is not a good quantum number?
I know it is not good for particles with mass, but I don't know why? Maybe it is not Lorentz invariant, if it is correct, could you please explain it? 

This question is relevant and might be helpful even though it has no answers. You should also try searching this site for related posts.

Can you boost to a frame where the helicity appears different?

The WP site you are adducing for helicity expressly sends you to the WP site where it is derived: why did you skip it?

This depends on what you mean by a "good quantum number."  In the usual sense, of commuting with the Hamiltonian, helicity absolutely is a good quantum number for free particles.  (In nonrelativistic quantum mechanics, all three spin projection operators commute with the Hamiltonian, although they don not commute with each other.  However, in the Dirac theory, the transverse spins do not commute with the Hamiltonain, although the longitudinal spin component--that is, the helicity--does.) For this reason, it is standard to describe the states of relativistic particles by labeling their helicity.
On the other hand, the helicity of a massive particle is not invariant under Lorentz transformations, which you seem to understand.  By transforming to the rest frame of a massive particle, you can ensure that, in that frame, $\vec{p}\cdot\vec{\Sigma}=0$.  However, for massless particles, which move at the speed of light, the helicity is preserved under such boosts.

@ Buzz, Thanks alot, this answer is very helpful.
